# UIActivity Controller linkedIn Post is not working

Tags: ios, share, linkedin-api

LinkedIn Sharing is not working in UIActivity view controller(Without SDK), while trying to share the post. LinkedIn post is getting crashed and I am getting a crashlog like linkedIn : plugin com.linkedin.LinkedIn.ShareExtension invalidated

```
NSArray *items = @[shareContentHeadingString,shareUrl];

    activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                              initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];

    NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                   UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,
                                   UIActivityTypePostToWeibo];

    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

    if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")){

        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
    }
    if([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")) {
            sharePopOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:activityViewController];
            shareRect = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2, 1, 1);
            sharePopOverController.delegate = self;
            [sharePopOverController presentPopoverFromRect:shareRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];
        }
        else{
            [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }
    else{
        [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you've tried?

Comment: I am not mentioning activity type in activity controller. @khuong291

Comment: Please refer this code http://dpaste.com/1296X2W @Panda

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem. then i removed URL and Image and passed only string value to LinkedIn. and it worked.